# typescript : logic to covert string array into custom object

Tags: javascript, typescript, logic, typescript2.0

Here is my requirement. I was able to achieve to some level in java but we need to move it to typescript (client side).

*Note:* The below input is for example purpose and may vary dynamically.

*Input*

```
var input = ["a.name", "a.type", "b.city.name" , "b.city.zip", "b.desc","c"];
```

We need to create an utility function that takes above input and returns output as below.

*Output*:

**Should be string** not an object or anything else.

```
"{ a { name, type }, b { city  {name, zip } , desc },  c }"
```

any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `{ a { name, type }, b { city  {name, zip } , desc },  c }` what is this? that's not javascript.

Comment: And you didn't try anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see that typescript plays any role in your question, but here's a solution for constructing the string you requested. I first turn the array into an object with those properties, then have a function which can turn an object into a string formatted like you have

```js
const input = ["a.name", "a.type", "b.city.name" , "b.city.zip", "b.desc","c"];

const arrayToObject = (arr) => {
  return arr.reduce((result, val) => {
    const path = val.split('.');
    let obj = result;
    path.forEach(key => {
      obj[key] = obj[key] || {};
      obj = obj[key];
    });
    return result;
  }, {});
}

const objectToString = (obj, name = '') => {
  const keys = Object.keys(obj);
  if (keys.length === 0) {
    return name;
  } 
  
  return `${name} { ${keys.map(k => objectToString(obj[k], k)).join(', ')} }`;
}

const arrayToString = arr => objectToString(arrayToObject(arr));

console.log(arrayToString(input));
```

Comment: Conversion of array into object does the trick and makes further logic easier.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another variation. Trick is to parse the strings recursively and store the intermediate results in an Object.

```js
    function dotStringToObject(remainder, parent) {
      if (remainder.indexOf('.') === -1) {
       return parent[remainder] = true
      } else {
     var subs = remainder.split('.');
        dotStringToObject(subs.slice(1).join('.'), (parent[subs[0]] || (parent[subs[0]] = {})))
      }
    }
    
    var output = {};
    ["a.name", "a.type", "b.city.name" , "b.city.zip", "b.desc","c"].forEach(function(entry) {
     dotStringToObject(entry, output)
    });
    
    var res = JSON.stringify(output).replace(/\"/gi, ' ').replace(/\:|true/gi, '').replace(/\s,\s/gi, ', ');
    console.log(res)
    // Prints: { a { name, type }, b { city { name, zip }, desc }, c }
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this:

```js
var input = ["a.name", "a.type", "b.city.name" , "b.city.zip", "b.desc","c"];
var output = {};
for(var i =0; i < input.length; i+=2){
    output[String.fromCharCode(i+97)] = {};
    output[String.fromCharCode(i+97)].name = input[i];
    output[String.fromCharCode(i+97)].type = input[i+1];
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(output));
```

Comment: the output must be a **string** not an object

Comment: Oh man! Is really dificult do this: "JSON.stringify(output);".

Comment: doing this will not output the same result as asker expects